# Designing edit profile screen

Tags: mobile, android, user-profile

I am designing edit profile screen for android mobile app have several fields (profile pic, full name, username, intro, career, interests and etc) to filled out by the user.

Possible user flows

1. Profile -> Edit profile -> Edit intro (separate screen to edit a specific field)
2. Profile -> Edit Profile (edit on the edit profile screen itself)
3. Profile -> Edit Profile -> Dialog to edit a specific field

Pros and cons of the each approach as I see.

1. **Pro:** No clutter with other due to other fields, **Cons:** 1 more click for user to edit a particular info.
2. opposite of the first approach
3. similar to first approach

For now I have total of 9 fields, it may increase in the future. So what is best approach to to give optimal UX for the user when editing profile?
Any tips, more things to consider are welcome.

I was not able to find UI mocks on this topic, so UI mocks of edit profile screens are welcome.

Comment: how often is the user going to edit his/her profile?

Comment: rarely. may be once in app usage, once a year

Answer (score 2):

1. Split profile into small sections like Name, Contact Info (phone, email, etc.), Address, Password, Preferences. Yes, it will cost one more click. But profile is not changed often that's why it is fine. Advantage: User has overview of all fields editable at the moment and can avoid occasional unintended modifications and thus avoid errors. This is especially important for mobile devices.
2. You show all possible fields. But show in a display (read only) mode. Allow editing one field at a time. To edit a field user clicks on an icon right to the field, edits the field and saves the changes. Then again, no risk of unintended modifications, and good overview of all fields in profile.

Comment: Thanks for the response. actually thats what I did finally, split into tabs. sections in the same page is overwhelming since there is a lot

Comment: @user158: You said "I have total of 9 fields". You can split it into 2-3 sections. How can it be overwhelming?

Comment: @user158: I added one more solution to the answer. Check if it fits your needs.

Comment: since there is lots of scrolling to find specific field.

Comment: @user158: I added one more solution to the answer. Check if it fits your needs.

Comment: since some are text areas

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one click away is not a con, and tucking things under the bed if they are not being used often, is the way to go on web nowadays.
https://uxmyths.com/post/654026581/myth-all-pages-should-be-accessible-in-3-clicks

If the user is not expected to edit much, then yes, take them to a different contextual page, and let them meddle with it until they settle with it. I vote for 1. (Again this depends on how often they are expected to edit, and profiles are usually done once).

Comment: Do you think its overwhelming allow user edit 9 fields in the same screen when provided with proper spacing and edited rarely

Comment: On mobile they may look a lot, but do not break them into multiple unless there is a peice of data that you want so badly, and don't care about the others. I would make them in sections, with nice headers, or two columns on desktop. Keep the ones most important at top. One save button. (better yet, save as you go, like google does).

Comment: So you would not recommend, using [text field with jumping label in MD](https://material.io/components/text-fields/)?

Comment: That's a design decision.. "save as you go" as in: user changes something, then blurs the field, it autmatically saves to server, no "save" button... again, you really do not have to for pages that are used once in a year.

Comment: I am not taking about saving here. I am talking about text field style in MD? as you said to use headers instead of provided hint text

Comment: I mean headers of field groups, those are labels of individual inputs